# How can I bridge my router to my Linux OS?

Tags: linux, denial-of-service

I am getting ddosed a bit so I want to send all my router traffic to my Linux OS as a somewhat mitigation. How to send my router traffic to my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer: You can't

Long Version: It depends on your Networking Knowledge and on your Router Model. If it is just a SOHO router you can't.

If you have a Professional Router 19" Rack Mounted (Cisco, Brocade) the you should be able to do this by creating a Port Mirror of your Incoming WAN Port to one of the LAN Ports where you then Plug in Your PC.

I think the best for You will be to search the Contact with Your Provider and Ask if they can set up a Monitoring for The Traffic coming to you.

Comment: im on a BTHUB5 router

Comment: @AriesFangz You can't with that router... You should contact your ISP.